# Redirect subdomain to hosting folder

Tags: apache, redirect, dns, server, hosting

I have my main domain address pointing to Squarespace.

I want to redirect a subdomain of that domain to my hosting folder. Right now the address of my folder in the hosting is like this: `myserverIP/~hostingusername/website/`

So what I want to achieve is this redirect:

```
www.domain.com --> mysite.squarespace.com
subdomain.domain.com --> myserverIP/~hostingusername/website/
```

Squarespace redirect works well but not the subdomain.

On the domain settings, I created an A record with the subdomain (`subdomain.domain.com`) pointing the `myserverIP` but since the site is not on the root IP but on a folder I don't know how to redirect to it.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?